# Trying to install Net::OpenSSH but getting back invalid version for dependencies

Tags: perl, ssh, versioning, perl-module

I'm working with some perl 5.8.8 legacy code and I usually check my installed packages with    `perl -MNet::OpenSSH -e 'print "worked \n"'`

If it's absent it states:

```
Can't locate Net/OpenSSH.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .).
        BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Which is normal. Then I run cpanm  and it installs. However, with this OpenSSH module I am getting back that some dependencies are not a valid version.

```
kristen:/web# cpanm Net::OpenSSH
install is up to date. (0.01)
--> Working on Net::OpenSSH
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SA/SALVA/Net-OpenSSH-0.62.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Net-OpenSSH-0.62 ... OK
Failed to clean-up 2 metadata. Errors:
'version=HASH(0x8eb66f4)' for 'Test::More' is not a valid version. (prereqs -> runtime -> requires -> Test::More) [Validation: 2]
'version=HASH(0x8eb6700)' for 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker' is not a valid version. (prereqs -> configure -> requires -> ExtUtils::MakeMaker) [Validation: 2]
'version=HASH(0x8eb69f4)' for 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker' is not a valid version. (prereqs -> build -> requires -> ExtUtils::MakeMaker) [Validation: 2]
```

I used `cpanm upgrade Test::More` which didn't resolved the problem for that module so I think I need a lower version number. So how do I check what versions I need to use Net::OpenSSH?

Comment: If you run: `perl -MCPAN -e shell` and then `o conf` you'll see a `prerequisites policy` or similar. What does that say? If you set it to `follow` it'll download anything needed to install the package.

Comment: Presumably you're on RHEL5, which has 5.8.8 by default? It is a rather old version though, so upgrading wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: try upgrading cpanm (App::cpanminus) first

Comment: @Sobrique I ran `o conf` and `prerequisites policy` is set to `follow`. That was expected, I suppose, since I have installed maybe over 30 modules in the past, but this is the first one that's given me dependency trouble. And yes, we are using Red Hat/CentOS...I'd love to upgrade from 5.8.8 but it's not possible at this time for business reasons.

Comment: Yeah, I know that problem - I've hit it plenty of times. You _can_ parallel install a new version of perl in `/usr/local`.  (That's the default path). Failing that though, I'd suggest look at `yum list` and see if there's a suitable package to install. Some of them - like SSL based stuff - comes pre-compiled.

Comment: Try upgrading `version.pm`

Comment: @ysth upgrading cpanm did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading cpanm and then installing the module resolved the issue.